# Button onClick is not referenced properly and output is not as expected

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the variable template and using **AddCard** function to be called when button is clicked but is not read correctly when I inspect the element.

It looks something like this in Console:
[image: Error in Console]

But is should look something like this :

```
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="AddCard("CSE101")" value="Add">
```

Here is the code I have used to get the ID.

```
var template = " <div class='mycard text-center col-md-2' id ='"+obj.Course+"'> <div class='card-header'> <p1>"+ obj.Course +"</p1> </div>  <div class = 'card-block'>   <div id = 'svgcontainer"+i+"'> </div>  </div> <div class = 'coursename'> <p2> "+obj.CourseName+" </p2> </div> <div class='contact-submit' > <input type='button' class ='btn btn-success btn-xs' onClick = 'AddCard('"+ obj.Course +"')' value='Add' > <input type='button' class ='btn btn-danger btn-xs' onClick = 'SkillVis2();this.disabled=true' value='Play'> </div> <div class='card-footer text-muted'> Prof. XYZ </div> </div>"

function AddCard (corsename)
{
var obj = _.find(data, function(obj){ return obj.Course == corsename; });
SkillVis(obj);
};
```

Comment: @CaffeineFueled
 what you wrote is printed in console... Real Code is in 
var template 
onClick = 'AddCard(' "+ obj.Course +" ')' value='Add'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use escape characters to avoid this issue:

```
onclick="AddCard(\"CSE101\")"
```

Another possibility is to use single quotes for the parameter:

```
onclick="AddCard('CSE101')"
```

For your js-string, the solution would be:

```
onClick =\"AddCard('" + obj.Course + "')\"
```

Comment: onClick = 'AddCard(\ ' "+ obj.Course +"\ ')', didn't make any change to it.

Comment: @hawkeye that's what you get for trying to solve things without checking them. :D Edited my answer. :)

Comment: onclick="AddCard('CSE101')" , now this is what I got. But I think I shoud get
 onclick="AddCard("CSE101")"

Comment: No, your last example will never work: you can't have double quotes like that: they're nested. The solution you have right now should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
"onClick = 'AddCard("+ obj.Course + ")' "
```

Shouldn't it be just like that?

Comment: There is no balance in " " I think.

Comment: Sorry, SO was flipping. I have changed my answer. In short, I don't think your object should be between quotes

Comment: onClick = 'AddCard("+ obj.Course +")'  This is what I changed and output is something like this           onclick="AddCard(CSE101)"